# SQL Composite Indexes for between query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table called survey_results which will hold data about different surveys below you can find schema of that table.

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_results` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `survey_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `nameindex_on_account_id_and_survey_id` (`account_id`,`survey_id`),
  KEY `survey_results_id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_survey_results_on_acc_id_and_surv_id_and_created_and_group` (`account_id`,`survey_id`,`created_at`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I just added a new index `index_survey_results_on_acc_id_and_surv_id_and_created_and_group` for `survey_results` I have a filter on above four things thats why I created a new index on this table, **group** is optional.

**Problem :**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `survey_results`.id
FROM `survey_results`
WHERE `survey_results`.`account_id` = 1 AND 
      `survey_results`.`survey_id` = 14 AND
      (survey_results.created_at between '2016-05-31 18:30:00' and '2016-07-01 18:29:59') AND
      (survey_results.group_id = '4')
```

Above query is not fully using my index. It gets used for only account_id and survey_id.

If I query like below its working properly.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM `survey_results` WHERE `account_id` = 1 AND `survey_id` = 14 AND (survey_results.created_at = '2016-06-30 17:22:24') AND (survey_results.group_id = '4');
```

Then whats the problem with between query? What are all the changes required to make this efficient?

Comment: Why no `PRIMARY KEY`??

Comment: Your first and third KEYs are redundant; remove the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct index for your query is on `survey_results(account_id, survey_id, group_id, created_at)`.

All the columns in equality conditions should go first in the index.  Then you can add one key with an inequality condition, such as `between`.

Comment: In my case Group is an optional parameter. If I didn't use group It will not take that index right? Now I need to use one more index? or any good solution?

Comment: It will use the index for the first two columns, but not for `created_at`.

Comment: @ElayarajaT - then also have `INDEX(account_id, survey_id, created_at)`.  And, if you said `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, these would be "covering", adding some more performance.